# Apache 2 Test Page

Tags: apache, centos

I dont know why I see this Apache test page when I've configured my virtual host to point to my project?

**Server settings**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName malltomobiledev.com
DocumentRoot /home/dcms/public/html/dcms/app/web
<Directory "/home/dcms/public/html/dcms/app/web">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Apache restarted fine, so it was access the folders fine.

**My host file**

Ip  malltomobiledev.com

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using apache 2.2, make sure you have `NameVirtualHost *:80` set in your main apache config file, otherwise apache will use the default virtual host, which points to the test page.

You can check the configured virtual hosts using `apachectl -S`